# How can I fully cuztomize my keyboard modifiers in xkb?

Tags: linux, x11, xkb, xmodmap

I am using a ThinkPad laptop with Arch Linux, and I am looking into the possibilities of remapping my keyboard layout + modifiers.

What I want to do is similar to what you can do with the [**QMK**](https://github.com/qmk/qmk_firmware) firmware [where you have multiple layers on your keyboard.](https://config.qmk.fm) But without being dependent on specific hardware.

I found some different ways to do it, example:

- xmodmap
- [klfc](https://github.com/39aldo39/klfc)

KLFC looks very simple and straight forward, yet I experienced some issues that I didn't understand, so I decided to dig a bit deeper.

Then I found out that (probably) the most basic way is to use **xkb** in **X11** and then inherit from the layout which I want, and modify it to my needs.

I looked in the system files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb` specifically in the `symbols` directory where I have been looking a bit around in the different files, and I found some documentation from 1996 about the "xkb" API, but I haven't read it all. That's why I'm here asking for help.

I found that the symbols files are following a specific pattern.

```c
key <AE01> {    [     1,    exclam      ]   };
```

So the AE01 is the first key on the first row, and it is looking like something like a `struct` in C with a list as an attribute.

The order of the list then depends on something I want to modify -- and this is my question.

The `1` on the first place in the list means that if I click the button without using any modifiers, then `1` will be printed to **stdin**, and the `exclam` means that if I use the modifier key `Shift` (or `capslock`) then `!` will be sent to **stdin**.

I want to define my own modifier keys, (locked and latched). Maybe 10 different modifier keys. Some of them (locking) like `caps lock` and some of them (latching) like `shift` or `ctrl`, and I would like them to be independent (originals) so that I don't have to use something already defined.

I also want to have some of the (modifier keys) + (what they modify) to act together on a "deeper level". For example, I am using **i3** and I use `winKey` + n(0..9) to switch between the desktops, then when I move the numbers under the letters, and use `caps lock` + (some letters) to get the numbers, then the shortcut in **xkb** conflicts with the shortcut in **i3** and I don't get anything at all.

I guess that I will find out how to do all this If I just finish reading all the old documentation from 1994 for xkb, but I am hoping to find some nice clear tutorial, or hint which will get me started without having to take a whole **xkb** education. :)

Comment: Read [An Unreliable Guide to XKB Configuration (2004)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.600.7058) and see if you can get it to work the way you want. That will require quite a bit of work. I suggest making a completely new layout instead of modifying an existing one.

Comment: Thank you I will look at it now :)

Comment: [XKB on Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_keyboard_extension) is also a source of very useful insight into this dark land.

Comment: I am looking into changing my keyboard layout and adding QMK like features in particular home row mods. It seems like most people mention kmonad for this but I have not used it yet